# Force update drawForeground on QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I want to show a little image on my mouse position.

So i did that:

```
void AreaScene::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){
    MapData::pEnd.setX(event->scenePos().x());
    MapData::pEnd.setY(event->scenePos().y());
    this->update(0, 0, this->width(), this->height());
}
```

The pEnd is my point.

On the drawForeground i did that:

```
void AreaScene::drawForeground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect){
qDebug() << "called";
    if(MapData::tileIndex!=-1&&MapData::pEnd.x()!=-1){

        painter->drawPixmap(MapData::pEnd.x(),MapData::pEnd.y(), *MapData::tileImage, (((int)(MapData::tileIndex%(MapData::tileImage->width()/MapData::tileSize.x())))*MapData::tileSize.y()),
                      (((int)(MapData::tileIndex/(MapData::tileImage->width()/MapData::tileSize.x())))*MapData::tileSize.x()),
                       MapData::tileSize.x(), MapData::tileSize.y());
    }
}
```

Note:
The tile index is the position of the subrectangle on the tileImage (QPixelMap)
So i get the points, the image and the subrectange inside it.

It works if i keep pressing the right or the left mouse buttons it updates, but i want to update it when i move the mouse, i know the drawForeground is not even called at all.
Is there a way to call it, force to update so i can show the little tile on the screen?

The another option (i think) is change the mouse icon to the tile image, but i did a little research and didn't find a way to do that.

Thanks ppl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `setMouseTracking(true);` on the QGraphicsView that is displaying the scene. That will tell the view to generate mouse move events whenever the mouse is hovered over the view. Otherwise, the view will only generate mouse move events when you click and drag while holding down a mouse button.